# Help choosing correct resistor

Tags: resistors

as you can see from the pic, the resistor is burnt out.
It has written on it…
ER G – 74ER – 1R8 – 5% - 7634
This is all I can make out, any help appreciated in choosing a replacement.
It’s from a crossover circuit within a set of speakers.[image]

Comment: This is not an electronics repair site, your question may be considered off-topic.

Comment: 1R8 is probably the resistance, ie 1.8 ohms.  But draw a schematic of the board to verify that 1.8 ohms is a reasonable value for that resistor.

Answer (score 5):

Fortunately, most of the specifications are written on it:

- 1R8 means 1.8 ohms
- 5% is the tolerance

The only thing which is missing is the power. Fortunately, power and size are pretty closely related, so any resistor which is the same size or larger is probably fine.  In fact, given that this part has burned out, I'd be inclined to replace it with the largest/highest power resistor which fits between the holes it's soldered into.

Also, that resistor looks like it's wirewound.  So I'd be inclined to replace it with another wire-wound resistor, so that the parasitic properties are similar. Just to be on the safe side.

Comment: While you're in there, check the values of those bipolar electrolytics. And I'd do the same on the other channel.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jack, the resistors seem to be wirewound but you can also use metal film.

I'm adding this extra answer to recommend you solder the replacement resistor with "long legs" to make it stand off the board about a centimeter. This lets the air circulate better around it, it will have better cooling.

Also if you pay $5 shipping fee or burn some gas to drive to the shop, really there's no harm in spending a few extra cents for a higher wattage resistor...

Comment: Sorry if it was off topic, many thanks to everyone who gave constructive comments you were very helpful and informative. Have a great weekend everyone.